Refresh ReactJS Tanstack table after removing a record with action dropdown
I created a data table using ChadCN’s guide, which uses @tanstack/react-table. Each row has a dropdown menu with three dots, allowing the user to remove the row. The dropdown triggers a removeDomain server function that deletes the database entry by ID, and it works fine.
However, the table does not refresh after the row is removed. I want to update the table without a page reload. I tried using callback functions, but I’m struggling to integrate them due to the dynamic column and row construction in TanStack.
This is the component with the delete action:
export function DataTableRowActions<TData>({
  row,
}: DataTableRowActionsProps<TData>) {
  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          className="flex h-8 w-8 p-0 data-[state=open]:bg-muted"
        >
          <MoreHorizontal />
          <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
        </Button>
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent align="end" className="w-[160px]">
        <DropdownMenuItem
          onClick={() => {
            const id = (row.original as { id: number }).id;
            removeDomain(id); //imported server function
          }}
        >
          Delete
        </DropdownMenuItem>
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
}

The dropdown component for the “Remove” action is called from the component that builds the columns:
export const getDomainColumns: ColumnDef<initialDomain>[] = [
  {
    accessorKey: "domain",
    header: ({ column }) => (
      <DataTableColumnHeader column={column} title="Domain" />
    ),
    cell: ({ row }) => {
      return (
        <div className="flex space-x-2">
          {/* {label && <Badge variant="outline">{label.label}</Badge>} */}
          <span className="max-w-[500px] truncate font-medium">
            {row.getValue("domain")}
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "createdAt",
    header: ({ column }) => (
      <DataTableColumnHeader column={column} title="Date Added" />
    ),
    cell: ({ row }) => {
      return (
        <div className="flex space-x-2">
          {/* {label && <Badge variant="outline">{label.label}</Badge>} */}
          <span className="max-w-[500px] truncate font-medium">
            {row.getValue("createdAt")}
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    id: "actions",
    cell: ({ row }) => <DataTableRowActions row={row} />,
  },
];

This is where the table component is called, and the columns and data is given. The columns are given using the component above.
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-4 p-4 pt-0">
      <div className="min-h-[100vh] flex-1 md:min-h-min">
        <InitialDomainsDataTable
          columns={getDomainColumns}
          data={initialDomains}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

The column data is used to build the TanStack table in the InitialDomainsDataTable component.
  const table = useReactTable({
    data: domains,
    columns,
    state: {
      sorting,
    },
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
  });


What would be the best way to solve this?
